# Speex installation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, speex

I have trouble with installing a Speex library for Visual Studio Community 2015!

The Install file contains only:

```
*% ./configure [--prefix=<install-path>] % make % make install*
```

If it's impossible please suggest a different library for sound compression
(Another than opus :D )

Comment: You might want to explain what type of trouble you are having.

Comment: Well, i dont know where to start since this is for Linux i belibe. There is a win32 folder with VS for it but it is not building